# PHP and regex Task

Tags: php, regex

I have a string in php formatted like this:

```
http://aaaaaaaaaa/*http://bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
```

where aaa...  and bbb.... represent random characters and are random in length.

I would like to parse the string so that I am left with this:

```
http://bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
```

Comment: will it always be in that format of http://aaaaaaaaaa/*http://bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I wouldn't recommend regex but a simple substring or explode

```
$data = "http://aaaaaaaaaa/*http://bbbbbbbbbbb"
$parts = explode('*', $data);
echo $parts[1];
```

fin :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regular expressions at all in this case:

```
$str = 'http://aaaaaaaaaa/*http://bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb';
echo substr($str, strpos($str, 'http://', 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the regular expression way:

```
$str = 'http://aaaaaaaaaa/*http://bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb';
$url = preg_replace("/^.*(http:\/\/.*[^(http:\/\/)+])$/", "$1", $str);
echo $url;
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi This would help you to get the address:

```
$str = 'http://www.example.com/*http://www.another.org/';
$pattern = '/^http:\/\/[\.\w\-]+\/\*(http:\/\/.+)$/';
//$result = preg_replace($pattern, '$1', $str);
$found = preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $result);
$url = (!$found==0) ? $result[1][0] : '';
echo $str . '<br />' . $url;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a clean solution: grab everything after the last occurrence of "http://".

```
$start = strrpos($input, 'http://');
$output = substr($input, $start);
```